# Dojo + Rails 3.2.8 + CoffeeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dojo, coffeescript

I'm trying to use Dojo Toolkit 1.8 instead JQuery in a Rails 3.2.8 web application, mainly due of the lack of a complete and visually uniform widget based on JQuery. Followed these steps:

- Unzip dojo, dijit and dojox directories into app/assets/javascripts
- Changed in application.js `//= require_tree .` to `//= require_directory .`
- Edited application layout (Not unobtrusive yet... just to effect of testing)

views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dojo</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag '/assets/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "dojo/dojo", :'data-dojo-config' => 'async: true' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body class='claro'>
  <%= yield %>
  <script>
    require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/ready"], function(parser, ready) {
      ready(function() {
        parser.parse();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- Created a controller named home and a template to the index action

views/home/index.html.erb

```
<input type="text" required="true" name="bday" id="bday" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" value=<%= localize(Date.today - 21.days) %> />
<button id="button1" type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Button 1</button>
```

Ok, Dijit works nice! But when I try to put some dojo code within a CoffeeScript file (assets/javascripts/home.js.coffee), a **"ReferenceError: require is not defined"** error message is raised on Firebug console. Sample code:

```
require ["dojo/domReady!"], () ->
  alert('ok')
```

If I put a `//= require dojo/dojo` before the code above, it runs, but all dojo modules are loaded (not just domReady) and a "Error: defineAlreadyDefined" is raised on Firebug.

Is there any way to call the require function without having to reload the entire dojo.js or even access a dojo global variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a slip of mine, I swapped the javascripts inclusion order. The correct is:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag '/assets/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "dojo/dojo", :'data-dojo-config' => 'async: true' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

Dojo wasn't loaded yet when I was trying to require modules within the coffeescript file.

Thank you for your attention.