# How to structure a project with RoR and dojo to build dojo AMD modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dojo

One issue I am working with is how to structure a RoR project that is also structured to create dojo AMD modules.  RoR has strong file structure "requirements" and all the tutorials/documentation for dojo have their own "requirements" and the two don't seem to mesh.

Has anyone built a project to accomplish this and just how did you manage the directory structures.  A clear point of concern is how the dojo modules and widgets live in the asset pipeline during development.  I don't want to develop the dojo modules in one project then move to a different project to use those modules.  Much more efficient to be able to develop the RoR project and the dojo together.

I am currently using the dojo-rails gem but I am not committed to it by any means.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Working with Dojo is pleasure . In my project , I've copied Dojo's components in vendor/assets/javascripts (I have folders dojo , dojox and dijit ) . In my appilcation.html.haml :

```
              = stylesheet_link_tag "application"
          = csrf_meta_tags
          / More ideas for your <head> here: h5bp.com/d/head-Tips
          /
            All JavaScript at the bottom, except this Modernizr build incl. Respond.js
            Respond is a polyfill for min/max-width media queries. Modernizr enables HTML5 elements & feature detects;
            for optimal performance, create your own custom Modernizr build: www.modernizr.com/download/
          = javascript_include_tag "modernizr"
          = javascript_include_tag "dojo/dojo", :'data-dojo-config' => %Q(baseUrl: '/assets/dojo/', modulePaths: {modules: '/assets/modules', widgets: '/assets/widgets', parseOnLoad: true})
%body
```

It works fine and it's fantastic .

EDIT : It was interesting for me to research how to use Dojo with assets pipeline . I've found an [interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391840/dojo-rails-3-2-8-coffeescript?rq=1) about including the source of Dojo in the right place - app/assets/javascript .

Comment: I understand that you are basically bypassing the asset pipeline which I get.  My real concern is in dojo development beyond using the base dojo classes.  In the tutorials (http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modules/) for developing modules they recommend a structure of:
/
  index.html
  js/
    lib/
      dojo/
      dijit/
      dojox/
    my/
    util/

So how to fit this into the RoR directory structure and have both environments play nice.

Comment: You are absolutely right , I'm using base Dojo classes . I'd love to see the right solution .